# Why is my second object created from my Board class not printing out the same game board filled with battleships like my first object?

Tags: java, arrays, output

I'm creating a Battleship game for my Java course (might not be the best code structure or the neatest but I'm trying). I'm running across a problem where I create two objects from my Board class and only one of the objects prints out a board game filled with water and battle ships while the second one if not filled with battleships. I'm confused to why the second object won't print out the same results as the first objects if they're completely different objects themselves I thought that's how object oriented programming worked? I've tried even creating a second createBoardGame2() method to see if that would help it create a different result if the original method stopped working after using it for the first object for some reason.

```
public class Main {
    public static char hit = 'X';
    char miss = 'O';
    public static char water = '-';
    public static char ship = 'S';
    int i = 0;
    public static Board board = new Board(10, 10, water, ship);
    public static Board playerOwnBoard = new Board(10, 10, water, ship); // Creates opponent board game which we will do guesses on
    public static int shipsNum = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        playGame();

    }

    static void playGame() {
        playerOwnBoard.printBoardGameOwn(playerOwnBoard.createBoardGame());
        board.printBoardGameOwn(board.createBoardGame());

        int undetectedShipNumber = shipsNum;
        
    }

}

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Board {
    private static final int xAxis = 10;
    private static final int yAxis = 10;
    // Symo
    public static char water = '-';
    public static char ship = 'S';
    public static char hit = 'X';
    public static char miss = 'O';
    // Number of ships allowed are no more than 1
    private static int placedShips = 0;
    private static int battleship = 0;
    private static int carrier = 0;
    private static int destroyer = 0;
    private static int submarine = 0;
    private static int patrolBoat = 0;
    private static int shipsNum = 5;
    private static final char[] BOARD_LETTERS = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'}; // Row input on grid
    //public static char[][] boardGame;

    public static int[][] carrierShip = new int[5][2];
    public static int[] guessCoordinates;
    public static char locationViewUpdates;

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  
    public char[][] createBoardGame() {
        char[][] boardGame = new char[xAxis][yAxis];
        for (char[] row : boardGame) {
            Arrays.fill(row, water);

        }
        return placeShips(boardGame);
    }

    public static void printBoardGameOwn(char[][] boardGame) {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= yAxis; i++) {
            System.out.print("\t" + i);
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int row = 0; row < boardGame.length; row++) {
            System.out.print(BOARD_LETTERS[j] + " | ");

            for (int col = 0; col < boardGame.length; col++) {
                char position = boardGame[row][col];
                if (position == ship) {
                    System.out.print(ship + " | ");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(position + " | ");
                }
            }
            j++;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static char[][] placeShips(char[][] boardGame) {
        int gameBoardLength = boardGame.length;
        while (placedShips < shipsNum) {
            int location = generateShipCoordinates(gameBoardLength);
            int location2 = generateShipCoordinates(gameBoardLength);

            char possiblePlacement = boardGame[location][location2];
            if (possiblePlacement == water && carrier == 0 && location2 < 6) {
                for (int q = 0; q < 5; q++) {
                    if (possiblePlacement == water) {
                        boardGame[location][location2] = ship;
                        carrierShip[q][0] = location;
                        carrierShip[q][1] = location2;

                        location2++;
                    }
                }
                carrier++;
                placedShips++;
            }
            else if (possiblePlacement == water && battleship == 0 && location2 < 7) {
                for (int q = 0; q < 4; q++) {
                    if (possiblePlacement == water) {
                        boardGame[location][location2] = ship;
                        location2++;
                    }
                }
                battleship++;
                placedShips++;
            }else if (possiblePlacement == water && destroyer == 0 && location2 < 8) {
                for (int q = 0; q < 3; q++) {
                    if (possiblePlacement == water) {
                        boardGame[location][location2] = ship;
                        location2++;
                    }
                }
                destroyer++;
                placedShips++;
            }else if (possiblePlacement == water && submarine == 0 && location2 < 8) {
                for (int q = 0; q < 3; q++) {
                    if (possiblePlacement == water) {
                        boardGame[location][location2] = ship;
                        location2++;
                    }
                }
                submarine++;
                placedShips++;
            }else if (possiblePlacement == water && patrolBoat == 0 && location2 < 9) {
                for (int q = 0; q < 2; q++) {
                    if (possiblePlacement == water) {
                        boardGame[location][location2] = ship;
                        location2++;
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                }
                patrolBoat++;
                placedShips++;
            }
        }
        return boardGame;

    }

    public static int generateShipCoordinates(int gameBoardLength) {
        int coordinates = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBoardLength; i++) {
            coordinates = new Random().nextInt(gameBoardLength);
        }
        return coordinates;
    }
```

[image: sample output]

Second boardgames should be filled like the first with different locations for the S

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
public char[][] createBoardGame() {
    char[][] boardGame = new char[xAxis][yAxis];
    for (char[] row : boardGame) {
        Arrays.fill(row, water);

    }
    return placeShips(boardGame);
}
```

Rhis code creates 2 different board games and fills them with water ( specifically "-" )...

**only one board game is filled with the battle ship but the second one is not filled** ...

*This is what is giving you unsatisfied output and this is your actual question and not "**my createBoardGame() does not create to different filled board games instead fills ups the first one but the second one stays blank.**"*

Comment: That didn’t help me actually. I mentioned that that’s what’s not giving me the output wanted on the second one already. My question was that why wouldn’t it if it creates my first object perfectly and my second one it doesn’t .

Comment: ok can you say me which part of the code fills or creates the object with the ships in it

Comment: Yes, placeShips() creates the ships and where they will be placed, while printOwnBoard() prints them out depending if the spot in the array has a ship or not placed, if it doesn't it will have a " - " symbol representing water, and if it does it will print out a "S" representing ship. The first object is created perfectly while the second object for some reason prints no ships.

Comment: under the placeShips() method on the second line `while (placedShips < shipsNum)` in your above code the value is set to zero only when the activity is created...and in the rest of the code the value keeps on incrementing ....so this could be the reason for not having the ships placed in the second object....when the placedShips count touch 5 it doesnt create more ships....solution :-" *set placedShips value to zero when u are creating a new object (second object) or somewhere else where you find it to be more effective*"

Comment: it was exactly this thank you. Either calling the placedShips and shipsNum variable fixed it or entering all the variables into the placeShips method and initializing them to 0 fixed it. thank you!